# While appending a file how to add new information underneath old information in text file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've attempted to create or append a text file if it already exists and I was able to do that after research. However I'm stuck in trying to figure out how to add information underneath old info.

For example I have a text file which contains `sam10`.

```
name = input('Your name?')
squad = group
number = input('A number?')
target = open(squad, 'a')
target.write(name)
target.write(str(number))
```

If I ran this all this does it add on to the text text file and end up with a text file (called group) like so: `sam10james5`.

How could I edit this code so that I end up with `james5` beneath `sam10`?
So I see it like this when I open the text file:

```
sam10
james5
```

Answer (score 2):

You only have to add a `"\n"`:

Change:

```
target.write(name)
```

With:

```
target.write("\n"+name)
```

Comment: Thanks I feel embarrassed after such a simple answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are just missing adding a 'new line':

`target.write(name)
target.write(str(number) + '\n')`

`write` will simply add the exact characters provided to the file, nothing more. You need to add the new lines as needed.